# can't display the image in GUI from mysql - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, scenebuilder

I have a MySQLConnect class which derives the image from MySQLServer and converts it from BLOB to a image, the MySQLConnect itself is working but i want to create a instance of it in Controller.java in order to be able to view the derived image from DB in the GUI

Here is the code for MySQLConnect:

```
package sample;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class MysqlConnect {
    /*
     * set the default variables for mysql connection
     * */
    private static final String url ="";

    private static final String user = "";

    private static final String password = "";


    public BufferedImage image()
    {
        System.out.println("I am in Image");
        try {
            System.out.println("trying to find  com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println("Success");

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select image from images where state = 1");

            if (rs.next())
            {
                java.sql.Blob blob = rs.getBlob(1);
                InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream(1,blob.length());
                System.out.println(!rs.next());
                System.out.println(in);

                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
                System.out.println(image);



                /*
                Display the image
                 */
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
                JFrame frame=new JFrame();
                frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                frame.setSize(500,800);
                JLabel lbl=new JLabel();
                lbl.setIcon(icon);
                frame.add(lbl);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                return image;

            }

            con.close();
            System.out.println("reached here");


        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Code for Controller.java:

```
package sample;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;


public class Controller
{
    private ImageView imageView;



    public void  SubmitButtonClicked(){System.out.println("it is Submitted ");}

    public void NextButtomClicked()
    {
        MysqlConnect image = new MysqlConnect();

        BufferedImage img = image.image();

        imageView.setImage(Image.impl_fromPlatformImage(img));

    }



}
```

Code for Sample.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Region?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="576.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <bottom>
      <VBox prefHeight="98.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <HBox prefHeight="159.0" prefWidth="648.0">
               <children>
                  <TextField promptText="Name:">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <Region HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Decline">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="25.0" right="25.0" top="50.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <Button layoutX="181.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#SubmitButtonClicked" text="Submit">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets right="10.0" top="50.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Button>
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </bottom>
   <left>
      <ImageView fx:id="imageView" fitHeight="341.0" fitWidth="284.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER_RIGHT">
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="8.0" />
         </BorderPane.margin>

      </ImageView>
   </left>
   <top>
      <HBox prefHeight="94.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="74.0" text="Previous">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" top="8.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Region prefHeight="166.0" prefWidth="144.0" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#NextButtomClicked" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="74.0" text="Next">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="8.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Error i get once i click the next button:

```
it is Submitted 
I am in Image
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
trying to find  com.mysql.jdbc.driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at sample.MysqlConnect.image(MysqlConnect.java:30)
    at sample.Controller.NextButtomClicked(Controller.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$5(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$5(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.Controller.NextButtomClicked(Controller.java:29)
    ... 58 more
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: Add mysql connector in your classpath

Comment: You shouldn't use deprecated method to convert the `Image`. Use [`SwingFXUtils.toFXImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html#toFXImage-java.awt.image.BufferedImage-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) instead or simply pass the stream to the constructor of `Image`. (This does not solve your issue with the classpath though.)

Comment: Is there a reason you are using some `Swing` and some `JavaFX` nodes?

Comment: @fabian I have used what you told me but in the end when i try to 
                Image image = toFXImage(img1, null);  it does not allow me to use java.awt.Image instead it forces me to convert i to Writable Image do you any alternate libraries for this case ?

Comment: I don't understand: You want to convert a `BufferedImage` to `javafx.scene.image.Image` and `SwingFXUtils.toFXImage` takes a `BufferedImage` as parameter and returns `WritableImage` which extends `javafx.scene.image.Image`. There shouldn't be a problem when assigning it to the `image` property of an `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to include driver jar for MySQL MySQL Connector Jar in your classpath.

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: do i have to do it for every Project or a Class? because the MySQLConnector Class is working fine on it's own but i am struggling to call the instance of it

Comment: @HovikHakobyan You need to make sure it's included in the classpath every time you run an application accessing your class. If you run both apps with different classpath there can be a difference.

Comment: @fabian thank you i will take into consideration next time, and it is working now since i configured the path,